# Article after "as" and before a scientific term or a proper noun

Tags: grammar, articles

Usually one uses an article after "as", such as "Music as a weapon". However, does this rule apply when the noun after the "as" is a scientific term/method (proper noun?) ?

Let's say I want to reference [Slashdot effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slashdot_effect). Which sentence is correct in this particular situation?

```
[...] - this is known as a Slashdot effect.
[...] - this is known as Slashdot effect.
```

Comment: "*The* Slashdot effect" may be more idiomatic, but it depends on the hidden portion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would say "This is known as the Slashdot effect." Since it is a specific and known effect, the definite article should be used.